# Using data from one page's textbox on another page on html/node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="txtUsername" class="form-label">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" required>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="txtPassword" class="form-label">Şifre</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Giriş Yap</button>
</form>
```

I want to assign the "txtUsername" data to the "value" part of the "txtUsername" section in the code below. How can I do that?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtUsername" 
  name="txtUsername" value="" placeholder="kullanıcı ismi" disabled=" disabled">
```

Note: the codes are in different .ejs files.

Comment: Are these different files? Or is one a partial that is displayed on the same page? If displayed on the same page you can do that with JQuery. If on different pages, you will have to send the username to the backend when you submit the form, store the value some how, and then send that value to the frontend when you render your second ejs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use localStorage for this purpose. at pageA you store your value and at pageB you fetch it and display it.
** note: this may not be a safe way to store/restore credential data, for that purpose i suggest you to use session or jwt.

PageA.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="" oninput="storeUsername()" id="txtUsername" />

    <script>
        function storeUsername() {
            localStorage.setItem("txtUsername", document.getElementById('txtUsername').value)
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PageB.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" value="" placeholder="kullanıcı ismi"
        disabled=" disabled">
</body>

<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem("txtUsername") !== null)
        document.getElementById("txtUsername").value = localStorage.getItem("txtUsername")
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use `document.getElementById("loginForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {  localStorage.setItem("txtUsername", document.getElementById('txtUsername').value) }):` and then in the new page: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => { const userName = localStorage.getItem("txtUsername") ||"";  document.getElementById("txtUsername").value = userName });`